# Does robots.txt apply to subdomains?

Tags: robots.txt

Let's say I have a test folder (test.domain.com) and I don't want the search engines to crawl in it, do I need to have a robots.txt in the test folder or can I just place a robots.txt in the root, then just disallow the test folder?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Each subdomain is generally treated as a separate site and requires their own robots.txt file.

Comment: Even if it's a virtual subdomain like the one ipage offers?

Comment: Likely, it depends on how its set up, but an easy way to tell is to go to your URL and see what file is accessed.     http://subdomain.domain.com/robots.txt <that is what the crawler is going to go by, its not going to care if there is a different one on http://domain.com when its crawling http://subdomain.domain.com

Answer (score 3):

When the crawler fetches `test.domain.com/robots.txt` that is the robots.txt file that it will see.  It will **not** see any other robots.txt file.

Answer (score 1):

If your test folder is configured as a virtual host, you need robots.txt in your test folder as well. (This is the most common usage).
But if you move your web traffic from subdomain via `.htaccess` file, you could modify it to always use robots.txt from the root of your main domain.

Anyway - from my experience it's better to be safe than sorry and put (especially declining access) files robots.txt in all domains you need to protect. And double-check if you're getting the right file when accessing:

```
http://yourrootdomain.com/robots.txt
http://subdomain.yourrootdomain.com/robots.txt
```

Comment: I have already thought of that but wont it conflict with each other?

Comment: It won't, as the crawler does not think about how the file is generated or where it comes from. It just calls the URL and fetches what is returned.